# Ford Fiesta while driving wheel pulls to one side, either right side or left side

Tags: ford, fiesta

I have an issue with ford-fiesta EXI 1.4 variant, When I drive for a while and if I keep steering straight car pulls to one side, either right side or left side.

Few things I have checked

1. Wheel alignment.
2. Tyre condition.
3. Power steering fluid leak.

All seems to be ok. Someone please give me suggestions

1. How to check if steering box is issue ?.
2. Is it safe to drive 700km ? with the above issue

Comment: This sounds like an alignment issue, how did you check it?

Comment: worn joints? worn suspension components? Is it dependant on the road surface / camber? Are the tyres in good condition? Properly inflated?

Comment: With the car stopped and the engine off move the wheel from side to side, does the steering wheel move but the tires stay still, or does the steering action translate directly to the wheels?

Comment: @GdD Thanks for your input,  i will check this and will update for next level of help, what i have tested is while driving in straight road i have  kept my stearing  straight, the car went one side.   Regarding alignment i have done on FORD service center.